# Look for Matches in Two Pairs Of Columns

Tags: google-sheets

| A | B | C | D |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Email_1 | 123123 | Email_1 | 123123 | True |
| Email_2 | 3423423 | Email_2 | 456456 | False |
| Email_3 | 1231234 | Email_3 | 123123 | True |

How can I return a match if the data of both pairs of columns A,B matches with a row on C,D?

Answer (score 3):

There's a few ways you could do this.  I'll suggest a simple logic statement.  A trick to matching on multiple columns is to combine those columns to make a single unique key to match on.

This would be the formula for the top row

```
=if(A1&B1=C1&D1,True,False)
```

If you want to expand that into an arrayformula so you don't need to repeat the formula, you can put this in cell E1 (in your example)

```
=array_constrain(ArrayFormula(if(A1:A&B1:B=C1:C&D1:D,True,False)),CountA(A1:A),1)
```

**Note my array_constrain is loose as it assumes you will always have content in column A.  You can do whatever you need on this to meet your own needs.  This is just there to show you the concept